# how to match /debate/days/views/908 in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match `/debate/days/views/(here should be 3 digits)`. 
`/debate/days/views/980` or `/debate/days/views/888` will be matched, but not `/debate/days/views/foo`
This is the regex I tried, but not work:

```
re.search(r'/debate/days/views/\d\d\d', href).group(0)
```

This is the error message:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Could anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: what is the value of `href`?

Comment: It will throw that error if the string does not match the pattern. Check if it matches first.  `m = re.search(r'/debate/days/views/\d\d\d', href) if m: print m.group()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the RE doesn't match, `re.search` returns `None`, not a match object, so you can't use `.group()` on it. You have to test whether it succeeded first:

```
found = re.search(r'/debate/days/views/\d\d\d', href)
if found:
    print found.group(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

At one point your expression does not match `href` and returns `None`, which does not have `.group` method of course. [Just use `try ... except` to handle this case](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#EAFP):

```
try:
    re.search(r'/debate/days/views/\d\d\d', href).group(0)
except ValueError:
    print "No match found for '{}'".format(href)
```